# How to write a function in jsp which can be called when the submit button is clicked

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have the following code:

```
<tr>
        <td>Text:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="myText" id="myText" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="Click to Submit"></td>
</tr>

    <%

    String selectSQL = "select * from INTERFACE where INTERFACE_SHORT_NAME='?'";

    try{

         Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); 
         Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
         "jdbc:xyz:thin:@abc:1521:pqr", "user", "pw");

          PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(selectSQL) ;

          statement.setString(1,request.getParameter("myText"));

          ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery();             

%>

    <TABLE BORDER="1">
        <TR>
            <TH>INTERFACE_SHORT_NAME</TH>
        </TR>
        <% while(resultset.next()){ %>
        <TR>
            <TD><%= resultset.getString("INTERFACE_SHORT_NAME") %></td>
        </TR>
        <% } %>
    </TABLE>
    <%  }
      catch(SQLException e){
                             System.out.println("Class not found ");  
                            }  
%>

</body>
</html>
```

I want the query to fetch data on the submit button click but I am finding it difficult to figure out the use of onClick. 
Also, the "setString" which i have written does not execute. I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: The button will send a post to the handler for the form it is in. Your sql will execute when the page loads, and not get called by the button press. You need to put the sql in another jsp (or preferably a backing class), and return the data back to the page for rendering. This will require co-ordination of the actions, of course.

Comment: Ok. I will try putting the sql in another jsp. But here, the sql requires user input and I guess that is where the setString is failing. Will the sql work even after even after putting it in another jsp @jr593

Comment: The sql query is still an issue. It is not substituting the user passed value in the query. I put some debug comments to check every line and the problem occurs at the "setString" line. It doesnt execute beyond that and jumps to catch @jr593

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your button as submit button -

```
<input type="submit" value="Click to Submit">
```

and make sure your put this button inside a form.

Comment: Hey thanks. It worked. But the sql query is still an issue. It is not substituting the user passed value in the query. I put some debug comments to check every line and the problem occurs at the "setString" line. It doesnt execute beyond that and jumps to catch

Comment: what error you are getting ?? and you are not closing your statement in finally block. this may cause issue.

Comment: delete the work folder, where your jsp get stored and try.

Comment: Finally it worked. The request.getParameter line had to be put outside the try block. Thanks for all the help!